# How to identify controls on web/windows application using c#?

Tags: c#, winapi

I want to identify controls like `textboxes`, `forms`, `dropdown` etc in another application using `C#`. The same functionality which is carried out by `Coded UI` test.

Can it identify any controls in any external applications?

Any idea how to do it or is it really possible to do?

Comment: The *[UI Automation API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327(v=vs.110).aspx)*

Comment: These are good for mouse/keyboard event capture but could not find something which will display the fact that it is a .net button once I click on the button. Similar to what coded UI does.